# Ошибка в файле .htaccess :virtualhost not allowed

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

Содержимое файла `.htaccess`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory />
     Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/html>
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteBase /
     RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как описано в документации Apache, директивы *VirtualHost* и *Directory* не допустимы в файле *.htaccess*. Просто уберите их и сохраните оставшиеся строчки в этот файл.

Или все эти настройки можно поместить в каталог конфигурационных файлов веб-сервера. В Debian-подобных дистрибутивах Linux это каталог `/etc/apache2/sites-available` (включение сценарием **a2ensite**).